# Identification of IC - Top marking number 3SDM

Tags: diodes, integrated-circuit, identification, logic-gates, gate-driving

I could not find the part number from the IC top marking. The top marking shows 3SDM. I am looking for the manufacturing part number of this top marking.

Added circuit diagram for better understanding

[image]

[image: photo of unknown device on PCB]

Comment: Could you comment for which application this circuit is working for? And if you know the around what block of PCB is this component mounted. Otherwise, it is difficult to identify.

Comment: Arumugam - Hi, FYI these are the current "[Component Identification Question Guidelines](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6710)". As already commented, the more information you can supply from that list, the better the chances of identification. Please add new information by editing the question, not by adding comments here. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have added circuit added for better clarity